# Error in fetching data from MySQL using Volley

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I want to fetch data from MySQL and show it in textview. I got error in log cat showing that " Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject". It works in Single Activity, while using Intent its not fetching data.

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editTextId,ed1;
private Button buttonGet;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);

    buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textViewResult,tv,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6;
private ProgressDialog loading;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    getData();
}

private void getData() {
   // String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

 //   if (id.equals("")) {
    //    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //    return;
 //   }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL;//+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String n="";
    String p2o5="";
    String k2o = "";
    String urea = "";
    String phos = "";
    String potash = "";
    try {
        /**/

       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        Log.e("response",""+jsonObject);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++) {
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            n = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_N);
            p2o5 = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_P2o5);
            k2o = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_k2o);
            urea = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_urea);
            phos = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_phos);
            potash = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_potash);
        } } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //   textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nEmail:\t" +address+ "\nAddress:\t"+ vc);
    //  textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name);
    textViewResult.setText("N:\t"+n);
    tv.setText("P2O5:\t"+p2o5);
    tv2.setText("K2O:\t"+k2o);
    tv4.setText("Urea:\t"+urea);
    tv5.setText("Phosphate:\t"+phos);
    tv6.setText("Potash :\t\t\t\t\t" +potash);
}
}
```

Config

```
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://........ag.php?id=";
public static final String KEY_N = "n";
public static final String KEY_P2o5 = "p2o5";
public static final String KEY_k2o = "k2o";
public static final String KEY_urea = "urea";
public static final String KEY_phos = "phos";
public static final String KEY_potash = "potash";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "agri_result_1";
```

Comment: Post your json response ...

Comment: i didn't get the response.

Comment: See if you can reduce your code sample to isolate the error and show exactly what error you get and where it is occurring.

Comment: You should post your model and json response. That is the problem. You get this error, when your json is an array and you want to convert it to object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all, I got the answer, its worked perfectly.

Main Activity

```
public void OnClick(View V){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",ed1.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Second Activity

```
 private void getData() {

    String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
   ading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);


    String url = "http://...../ooo.php?id=";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new       Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```